# Set imageview color using intent(another activity)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

Firstly my objective is to set imageview background color in one activity when user click on color choices in another activity. But I have no idea how to do it using intent. Perhaps I need to learn more.

This is my code in 1st activity

```
public class Games1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games1);

    ImageView wire1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView wire2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView wire3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView wire4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView wire5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    ImageView wire6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    ImageView wire7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    ImageView wire8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

    wire1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();




        }
    });

    wire2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    wire8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });





}
```

This is my code for 2nd activity(user choosing color)

```
public class SelectColor extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selectcolor);

    ImageView blue = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    ImageView orange = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.orange);
    ImageView green = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.green);
    ImageView brown = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.brown);
    ImageView white = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.white);



   blue.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           DJ.keepMusicOn();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(SelectColor.this, Games1.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);



       }
   });

    orange.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    green.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    brown.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    white.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });

    blue.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DJ.keepMusicOn();

        }
    });





}
```

And lastly this is my '.xml' for 2nd activity(user choosing color)

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zaidi.frame2.MainActivity2"
android:background="#ffffff">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose a color"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_above="@+id/green"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/green"
    android:clickable="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/brown"
    android:src="@drawable/brown"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/green"
    android:clickable="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:src="@drawable/green"
    android:layout_above="@+id/brown"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/orange"
    android:src="@drawable/orange"
    android:layout_above="@+id/green"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/green"
    android:clickable="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/white"
    android:src="@drawable/white"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/brown"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/green"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

hi you can easily do this task.
first of all add enum or give each color one code like
1 for red
2 for black
3 for orange etc.
then pass int in intent using intentobject.putextra("key",value) in value pass selected color code.
then in first activity check for color code and change color according to color code.

```
Intent colorIntent = new Intent(SelectColor.this, Games1.class);
colorIntent.putExtra("colorCode",1);
startActivity(colorIntent);
```

in second activity

```
Intent colorIntent = getIntent();
int colorCode= intent.getIntExtra("colorCode"); 
switch(colorCode)
{
    case 1:
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
          break;
    case 2:
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Black);
          break;
   case 3:
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Orange);
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `putExtra` with your `intent` and pass the desire `color`

```
blue.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           DJ.keepMusicOn();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(SelectColor.this, Games1.class);
           myIntent.putExtra("desireColor","blue");
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }
   });
```

and in `onCreate()` method of  your `Game1.class`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String yourColor= intent.getStringExtra("desireColor"); // for this example you will get blue color

if(yourColor.equals("blue"){
   image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
} else {
 // and so on for other images
}
```

you got your color and now you just do it what you want .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an indication in the intent, representing the color's id.
Replace android.R.color.holo_blue_dark with your own color resource.

```
 blue.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           DJ.keepMusicOn();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(SelectColor.this, Games1.class);
           myIntent.putExtra("color",android.R.color.holo_blue_dark)
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }
   });
```

Then, extract the color to resource 'yourColor', and do what you wish with it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games1);
    int yourColor = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("color");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectColor Activity`

```
blue.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           DJ.keepMusicOn();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(SelectColor.this, Games1.class);
           myIntent.putExtra("ImageColor", Color.BLUE);
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }
   });
```

Then in your `Games1 Activity` retrieve your selected color:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    int color = extras.getInt("ImageColor");
    wire1.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```